# PHP add +2 to the buffer returned by socket_recv

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I have the following code in PHP, I are converting this code from a c++ code.

Here is the C++ code, if you want to analyze then.

http://pastebin.com/hzX1A8mH

And here is the PHP Code.

```
// just read the size to avoid reading 2 messages at once
$this->m_MsgSize = socket_recv($Socket, $this->m_MsgBuf, 2, 0);

// for now we expect 2 bytes at once, it should not be splitted
$DataSize = (int) (ord($this->m_MsgBuf[0]) | ord($this->m_MsgBuf[1]) >> 8);
if(($this->m_MsgSize != 2) || ($DataSize > ($this->NetworkMaxSize - 2)))
{
    $this->ResetBuffer();
    return false;
}

// read the real data
$this->m_MsgSize += socket_recv($Socket, $this->m_MsgBuf + 2, $DataSize, 0);

$NewDataSize = (int) (ord($this->m_MsgBuf[0]) | ord($this->m_MsgBuf[1]) >> 8);

echo $NewDataSize."\n";

// we got something unexpected/incomplete
if(($this->m_MsgSize <= 2) || ($NewDataSize != ($this->m_MsgSize - 2)))
{
    $this->ResetBuffer();
    return false;
}

// ok, ...reading starts after the size
$this->m_ReadPos = 2;
```

The problem is in this line

```
$this->m_MsgSize += socket_recv($Socket, $this->m_MsgBuf + 2, $DataSize, 0);
```

Converted from this line from c++ code, the link is on the top of this question.

```
m_MsgSize += recv(socket, (char*)m_MsgBuf+2, datasize, 0);
```

When I write `($m_MsgBuf + 2)` the php returns `php only variables should be passed by reference`, and when I write `$m_MsgBuf += 2;` or `$m_MsgBuf = $m_MsgBuf + 2;` before or after `socket_recv`.. The next variable called `$NextDataSize` don't return any value.

The problem is.. how to return the buffer adding + 2 to the buffer variable in PHP?

Comment: The C code is using pointer arithmetic. PHP has no pointers.

Comment: Hmm.. Have any way to do this in PHP?

Comment: You need to understand what the C code is doing in detail and then translate it to PHP. Although PHP has no pointer arithmetic, you can achieve the same results using other techniques..